# Why does enclosing a command in double quotes affect aliases?

Tags: quoting, alias, ksh

I have an alias `rm='/bin/rm -i'` and I know that if I type `"rm" filename` in the command line, the alias will be ignored somehow and the normal rm command without the -i flag will be called, but I don't understand why this works.

I don't understand why `"rm"` works at all, considering...

> Enclosing characters in double quotes (‘"’) preserves the literal value of all characters within the quotes, with the exception of ‘$’, ‘`’, ‘\’, and, when history expansion is enabled, ‘!’. - [gnu.org][1]

... but it does work somehow. And it ignores my alias. How does this work?

Furthermore, I see these alias-ignoring command invocations in my organization's Korn shell scripts sometimes. But that's unnecessary, right? Because Korn shell scripts don't have access to shell-level aliases anyway?

[1]: [https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Double-Quotes.html#:~:text=Enclosing%20characters%20in%20double%20quotes,POSIX%20Mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Double-Quotes.html#:%7E:text=Enclosing%20characters%20in%20double%20quotes,POSIX%20Mode))%2C%20the%20%27%20!

Comment: I don't have a solid answer. I suspect the reason is encoded within the syntax parser.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very specific case: see

https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Aliases

> The first word of each simple command, **if unquoted**, is checked to see
> if it has an alias. If so, that word is replaced by the text of the
> alias.

That section of the manual notes several confusing aspects of aliases, and ends with:

> For almost every purpose, shell functions are preferred over aliases.

Comment: Also, according to the POSIX standard for shell command processing, [section 2.3.1 Alias Substitution](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_03_01) (emphasis added): "After a token has been delimited, but before applying the grammatical rules in Shell Grammar, a resulting word that is identified to be the command name word of a simple command shall be examined to determine whether it is an **unquoted**, valid alias name."

Comment: Thank you, both!